# GetRenderer().NativeView equivalent in Xamarin Forms version 3.5.0.274416

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a **StackLayout** whose *NativeView* I am trying to access in *Xamarin* iOS project.
For the Xamarin Forms version **4.6.800** the function is straight forward.

`var view = stacklayout1.GetRenderer().NativeView;`

where *stacklayout1* is a **StackLayout**

But in  Xamarin Forms version **3.5.0.274416**  the **GetRenderer** property is not visible .

Anyone have any idea or workaround to access **NativeView** of a **StackLayout** in version **3.5.0.274416**.

Comment: why can't you use latest XF4.8?

Comment: I am working in an app which was developed long back. Upgrading XF would mean test all other feature after upgrade.

Comment: yes, this the what we have to do. update, test and fix issues when using new version. XF5 brings even more breaking changes.